# Avoid CSS rules for both csstransforms and csstransforms3D with Modernizr

Tags: performance, css, modernizr

Modernizr adds classes to HTML elements. If a browser supports CSS' 3D transforms, it generally also supports CSS' 2D transforms. So if I want to apply different types of transforms based on feature detection I do:

```
.csstransforms .off-canvas-left{
  @include translate(-($off_canvas_width + $shadow_blur), 0);
}

.csstransforms3d .off-canvas-left{
  @include translate3D(-($off_canvas_width + $shadow_blur), 0, 0);
}
```

The problem (if it's a problem) is that on translate3D-capable devices, the first rule is also executed.

Is this a problem for performance? How could I prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not an issue. Performance wise it's practically impossible to tell the difference. It compiles to something very similar to the following which is done all of the time without issue:

```
.off-canvas-left {
    transform: /* Fallback value */ ;
    transform: /* Possibly unsupported value */ ;
}
```

In order to avoid this issue completely you'd either have to change the Modernizr code to check for the `.csstransforms` class when applying `.csstransforms3d` or do it after Modernizr has run by iterating through all elements with `.csstransforms3d` and removing the `.csstransforms` class. But, as it doesn't have any noticeable effect on performance, it's most likely not worth your effort.

To me the biggest downside to this happening is simply cluttering of class names, but that is very common with Modernizr and something only we as developers see anyway.